# How to correctly store a number of results in a DTO?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I have stored procedure attached to a DB which should return results from just a simple search. The query is added to my entity and calls a regular method. The problem I face is storing the results from this procedure to a particular DTO as a list.

Is there any way to effectively store the results from this stored procedure as a list to the DTO?

Below is what I have so far

```
Controller:

[Produces("application/json")]
    [RoutePrefix("api/jobs")]
    public class OutputController : ApiController
    {
        private TestCoastalToolsEntities _output;

        public OutputController()
        {
            _output = new TestCoastalToolsEntities();
            _output.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }        

        /**Search**/
        // POST: api/postsearch
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost, System.Web.Http.Route("postsearch")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostSearch(SearchInputDTO srequest)
        {
            OutputDTO<SearchInputDTO> output = new OutputDTO<SearchInputDTO>();
            SearchInputDTO SearchInput = null;
            var searchString = srequest.SearchValue.ToString();
            SearchInput.Results = _output.searchLog2(searchString);
            if (_oput != null)
            {
                output.Success = true;
                output.Results = _SearchInput.Results;
                var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(output);
                return Ok(json);

            }
            return Ok(_ot);
        }

    }
}
-------------------------------------
Search DTO:

namespace toolPortal.API.Data.DTO
{
    public class SearchInputDTO
    {
        public List<object> Results { get; set; }
        public SearchInputDTO(output output) {
            this.ID = output.ID;
            this.Name = output.Name;
            this.Job = output.Job;
            this.Start = output.Start;
            this.End = output.End;
            this.Logs = output.Logs;           

        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is that the stored procedure runs and stores the list of results to SearchInputResults. From there, those results should be stored in another DTO to be passed off on the return.

Comment: What does your search query return? After you've identified the return record type, you'll need to map each item's properties to the DTO properties e.g. `result.Name = dto.Name`. Then change `List<object> Results` to `List<MyDTOtype> Results`. [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) is a useful tool to assist in mapping your models.

Comment: The search should return the rows that match the string that was passed into it.I was looking into automapper but was not sure what the implementation entailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EF you will want to leverage `Select()` to map the entities to your DTO, though you will need to consider the entire structure of the DTO. For instance, what is the "Logs" data structure going to comprise of? Is it a single string value, a list of strings, or a list of log records?

Using `Select()` you need to leverage property setters, not a constructor accepting an entity.

So a pattern like this:

```
public class Entity
{ 
   public string Field { get; set; }
}

public class Dto
{ 
    public string Field { get; set; }
}

var dtos = context.Entities
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .Select(x => new Dto
    {
        Field = x.Field
    })
    .ToList();
```

Looking at your example with the constructor:
    public class Dto
    { 
        public string Field { get; private set; }

```
    public Dto(Entity entity)
    {
       Field = entity.Field;
    }
}

var dtos = context.Entities
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .Select(x => new Dto(x))
    .ToList();
```

This doesn't work with EF & Select. EF can map to an object, but only via properties and a parameterless constructor. There is a hack around this to be aware of, but avoid if you do see it:

```
var dtos = context.Entities
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new Dto(x))
    .ToList();
```

With the extra `ToList()` before the select, the call will work because EF will execute the query and return the list of entities, then the `Select()` will be performed as a Linq2Object query. The reason you should avoid this is because EF will select *all* properties from the entity, where we should only pull back the properties we care about. It's also easy to fall into a lazy-load performance trap if your Dto constructor population starts iterating over related entities. Using `Select` to load just the fields you need from an entity and any related entities allows EF to build an efficient query for just the data needed without any lazy load traps.

Using AutoMapper you can simplify this by setting up the mapping from entity to DTO then leveraging `ProjectTo<Dto>()`.

So, if you want a DTO to represent the results (such as a success flag, error message) with a collection of the results if successful:

```
[Serializable]
// Our results container.
public class SearchResultsDTO
{
    public bool IsSuccessful { get; private set; } = false;
    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<SearchResultDTO> Results { get; private set; } = new List<SearchResultDTO>();

    private SearchResultsDTO() {}

    public static SearchResultsDTO Success(ICollection<SearchResultDTO> results)
    {
        var results = new SearchResultsDTO
        {
            IsSuccessful = true,
            Results = results
        };
        return results;
    }
    public static SearchResultsDTO Failure(string errorMessage)
    {
        var results = new SearchResultsDTO
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage
        };
        return results;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SearchResultDTO
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Job {get; set;}
    public DateTime Start {get; set;}
    public DateTime End {get; set;}
    public ICollection<string> Logs {get; set;} = new List<string>();  
}
```

then to populate these from a DbContext: (Inside a Repository or wherever reads the data)

```
using (var context = new SearchContext())
{
    var results = context.Logs
        .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(sRequest))
        .Select(x => new SearchResultDTO
        {
            ID = x.ID,
            Name = x.Name,
            Job = x.Job,
            Start = x.Start,
            End = x.End,
            Logs = x.LogLines.Select(y => y.Line).ToList(),
        }).ToList();

     var resultDto = SearchResultsDTO.Success(results);
     return resultsDto;
}
```

This assumes that the log entry has a Job, name, start, end date/times, and then a list of "lines" or entries to display as "Logs".  (Where the Log table has a related LogLine table for example with the one or more lines)  This demonstrates how to leverage `Select` to map not only the log record into a DTO, but also to map related records into something like a collection of strings, or a collection of other DTOs can be done as well.

Once it selects the DTO, I have it fill a container DTO using static factory methods to populate either a successful read, or a failed read. (which can be set in an exception handler for example.)  Alternatively you can just new up a container class and populate properties, use a constructor /w parameters, or just return the list of DTOs. The SearchResultsDTO container is *not* referenced within the EF query.

Comment: Is there any way to incorporate this with the Stored Procedure I had created _output.searchLog2(searchString) without using the select statement?

Comment: Possibly, though I don't use Sprocs at all with EF other than kicking off occasional bulk operations, nothing bound to entities. EF is designed as a relational mapper, something to bind objects to and have it compose SQL queries from Linq expressions to avoid the need to write Sprocs.